# HTTP_REFERER is null when protocol changed

Tags: php, .net, apache, iis, web

When some https site redirects to http site (and vice versa), I can not get the HTTP_REFERER. How to solve the problem? It is very important for my application.

> This happened in both IIS and apache, php and c# .net

Comment: The main reason for not setting an HTTP Referrer header or equivalent is that this could be a security issue. The referrer contains "where you come from", this is private information, and should not be exposed to others, what use is it otherwise to have a secure site if everyone can track where you have been?

Comment: There's no way around this restriction, your only option is to use a different verification model. One such method is giving your users a key and require them to send that as a parameter with the request.

Comment: @SachinLubana what do you mean by different verification model?